# A function that will only start when the browser is refreshed ANGULAR 5

Tags: angular

does anyone know how I can create a function that will only run under the total refresh of the page. For example, I will click f5 or create a new tab in my browser. I do not want to use onInit or constructor because this function is called even if the page is not refreshed fully

Comment: put it inside the onInit of app.component file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngOnInit()` method of your main component (generally AppComponent[`app.component.ts`]). It will be invoked only once whenever page is being load.